# Accessing Evernote with python

Tags: evernote, python

I'm trying to write a script to access my Evernote notes via Python. My understanding from the docs/ChatGPT is that this is the necessary first part of the code to do so:

```
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient

client = EvernoteClient(token=dev_token, sandbox=False)
note_store = client.get_note_store()
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
EDAMUserException: EDAMUserException(errorCode=2, parameter='authenticationToken')
```

The way I generated my dev_token was by:

1. https://dev.evernote.com/.
2. Click on "Get an API key" in the top right corner of the page.
3. Filling out the form
4. Generating the consumer key/secret
   And then the dev token is:

```
dev_token = "YOUR_API_KEY:YOUR_API_SECRET"
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!